# how to convert QString into int in qt creator

Tags: c++, string, qt, int

I have seen one answer regarding to this same question but when I tried it with my problem it get confused.

here is my string,

```
bit_rate = "bitrate: 2334 kb/s"
```

I need to get the `2334` from this string and assign it into a integer variable..
how is this possible in qt creator. I tried `toInt()`, but it always gives `0` as the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert QString to int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633555/how-to-convert-qstring-to-int)

Comment: no thats the answer I mentioned above.but I couldn't use it as it is.due to suffix and prefix problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to get rid of the `bitrate:` prefix and `kb/s` suffix. The best way is to use `QRegExp` or `QRegularExpression` to extract the digit part of the string and then call `toInt()`.

Here's example:

```
QString str = "bitrate: 3543 kb/s";
int value;

QRegExp re("bitrate:\\s*(\\d+)\\s*.*");
if (re.indexIn(str) != -1) {
    value = re.cap(1).toInt();
} else {
    qDebug() << "String not matched.";
    return;
}
qDebug() << value;
```

Comment: thanx that exactly gave me the answer I wanted.

Comment: thanx @Googie for your answer. Because of it, I tend to use regular expressions for other parts in my code.

Answer (score 2):

The [reference page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html) has a ton of material on this. The easiest way to implement this is to split the string based on spaces, then convert the one you want to an Int.

Example:

```
QString str = "bitrate: 3543 kb/s";
QStringList lst = str.split(" ");
Int value = lst[1].toInt();
```

Comment: oops I was being silly. thanx ur answer gave me the result very easily..thank you very much.

Comment: @Mlarnt90 so the answer to duplicate question didn't help you? It's basically the same as this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
QTextIStream stream("bitrate: 3543 kb/s");
QString prefix, sufix;
int result;
stream >> prefix >> result >> sufix;
```